# Generating Bitmap to - BLOB

Tags: php, blob

Is it possible to generate a `BLOB string` of a bitmap image which using PHP ? ..  im not telling about storing the `BLOB` in database .. i just required to directly generate a **BMP -> BLOB**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure. If I understand correctly, you could just load up the image with [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/file_get_contents) to grab its raw data. According to the linked docs, that function is binary-safe.

```
$bmpblob = file_get_contents('path/to/file.bmp');
```

To "print" its content to the user, you'd want to issue the correct type header before it. I think it would be something like this:

```
<?php
$bmpblob = file_get_contents('path/to/file.bmp');

header('Content-type: image/bmp');
echo $bmpblob;
```

Comment: Thanks wiseguy !  .. is there way to `BLOB` as user uploads it ? .. i just dont want to save the image .. any idea ?

Comment: @Sudantha The web server automatically saves uploaded files to a temp location anyway. (e.g., `$_FILES['yourfile']['tmp_name']`) I don't know that you could prevent the web server from doing that, but from that point you can load it up as described above and not copy the file anywhere permanent. You can even immediately delete the temp file if you want.

Comment: wiseguy ! one prob ! whats the encoding of `file_get_contents` output ?

Comment: @Sudantha There isn't one to speak of. It's just raw bytes. What's the problem?

Comment: actually i need to keep this row data on a webs service and retrieve it back !

Comment: @Sudantha So, you need to store this across requests? If so, you'll need to store it somewhere (if not in a file or database, then some in-memory data cache).

Comment: I have a problem with 'file_get_contents' for *bmp* file extension and it doesn't work

Comment: @Borislav I think you would be best served by asking that as a new question so more people could see and answer it.

Comment: Here it is: stackoverflow.com/questions/20351073/imagecreatefromstring-for-a-bmp-file/